# Magento 2.3. How to add data using model?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, model, resource-model, savedata

I have two variants adding data using Model. Which variant is more rignt ?

Especially I want to ask about this
 `$slider->setDataChanges(true);`in first variant because I must set up `_hasDataChanges = true` if I want to save data.

1.Variant 
[image]

2.Variant

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per Magento standard, ***the second option is right to add a new record to an entity using the repository.***

If you want to  update exist then you have to load the record by a primary key using getById()

> ```
> $slider = $this->sliderRepository->getById('PKID');
>
> $this->sliderRepository->save($slider);
> ```